# Python: User enters number, then a letter, then outputs the letter the amount of times as the number says

Tags: python, string, integer, output, prompt

Python: User enters number, then a letter, then outputs the letter the amount of times as the number says:

for example

```
"Enter Integer": 4
"Enter Letter": a
```

OUTPUT

```
a
a
a
a
```

This is what I currently have, but I get name error, ' ' is not defined, ' ' being the letter

```
integer = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))

character = str(input("Enter a character, e.g. 'a': "))

for i in range(integer):
    print str(character)
```

If I typed 4, 4 it would give me

```
4
4
4
4
```

That works, but letters will not output, I'm new to python so you'll have to excuse me

Any ideas?

Link of Error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYtv8.jpg

Comment: cannot reproduce it. Looks fine to me

Comment: Ev. Kounis, could I post an imgur link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use raw_input for python 2.7.

```
integer = raw_input("Enter a positive integer: ")

character = raw_input("Enter a character, e.g. 'a': ")

for i in range(int(integer)):
    print character
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4915408/1998692) Stack Overflow question for explanation on input vs raw_input in python 2.7.

> In Python 2, raw_input() returns a string, and input() tries to run the input as a Python expression.
>
> Since getting a string was almost always what you wanted, Python 3
>   does that with input(). As Sven says, if you ever want the old
>   behaviour, eval(input()) works.

Comment: OP is probably working with Python2x. Otherwise the `4 4 4 4` would not print either

Comment: Yeah I can reproduce in Python 2x.

Comment: I've put the extra brackets in but its still not working, I will post a link to the above comment after authorisation of posting a link

Comment: Arcyaz: Use raw_input in python 2.7.

Comment: @cal97g you do not need to cast to `str` when using `raw_input()`.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis - correct, I've updated the answer and added an explanation of input vs raw_input

Comment: This worked!! raw_input seems the way to go for the version of python used with PyCharm

Answer (score -1):

You could use this website to learn typing python

[visualize python](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)

> python3

```
integer = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
character = str(input("Enter a character, e.g. 'a': "))

for i in range(integer):
    print(character)
```

> python2

```
integer = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
character = raw_input("Enter a character, e.g. 'a': ")

for i in range(integer):
    print character
```

Comment: this is not the problem here

Comment: @Ev. Kounis thanks for mentioning me, I do not notice the version problem, so I fixed my answer